# connecting vs code to gcp cloudshell via ss

Tags: visual-studio-code, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-shell

I'm trying to connect vscode to cloud shell through ssh.  I found the following article https://medium.com/@alex.burdenko/vs-code-happens-to-be-my-favorite-code-editor-and-ive-been-lucky-to-participate-so-many-diverse-952102856a7a.  I followed all the steps and I'm able to ssh via the command line.  However when I try to ssh via vscode I get an error.

This is what I have specified in the config file

```
Host tmp_user@35.186.145.21
   Port 6000
   ForwardAgent yes
   HostName tmp_user@35.186.145.21
   User tmp_user
   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/google_compute_engine
```

When I execute `gcloud alpha cloud-shell ssh --dry-run` I get the following

`/user/bin/ssh -t -p 6000 -i /home/tmpus/.ssh/google_compute_engine -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no tmp_user@35.186.145.21 -- DEVSHELL_PROJECT_ID=myprj 'bash -l'`

Comment: 1) What is the error? 2) Remove `tmp_user@` from `HostName`.

Comment: The error is "permission denied public key".  But I'm able just directly ssh into the cloud shell using `gcloud alpha cloud-shell ssh`

Comment: I also deleted the tmp_user@ from the HostName, but still end up with the same error.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Answer (score 4):

Google's Cloud Code extension for VS Code should automatically connect you to Cloud Shell via SSH.  You can use one of the documented links [here](https://cloud.google.com/code/docs/vscode/quickstart-remote-dev) to automatically install the extension and open a sample or you can install Cloud Code directly from the [marketplace](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=GoogleCloudTools.cloudcode) and utilize the command palette (ctrl/cmd-shift-p) to run `Cloud Code: Open in Cloud Shell...`.  This will also create the requisite entry in your host file but please keep in mind that IPs, host names, etc are temporary and only valid while the instance of your Cloud Shell session is live.  This is likely the reason your connection fails with access is denied.

Answer (score 0):

Remove "tmp_user@" from the `HostName` field.

Try this:

```
Host tmp_user@35.186.145.21
   Port 6000
   ForwardAgent yes
   HostName 35.186.145.21
   User tmp_user
   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/google_compute_engine
```

Comment: Also note that the HostName IP address changes occasionally. If you are developing on Linux/Mac, you may find this article helpful for automating ip address change: https://moegui.com/help/google-cloud-shell-development-environment.html

Answer (score 0):

When you create cloud shell with

```
gcloud cloud-shell ssh --authorize-session --dry-run
```

In the answer you have something like this:

/usr/bin/ssh -t -p 6000 -i /home/tmp_user/.ssh/google_compute_engine -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no tmp_user@35.186.145.21 -- DEVSHELL_PROJECT_ID=XXXXXXXX 'bash -l'

So you add StrictHostKeyChecking parameter (UserKnownHostsFile /dev/null because it's temporary).

Your config file is like this:

```
Host tmp_user@35.186.145.21
    Port 6000
    ForwardAgent yes
    HostName 35.186.145.21
    User tmp_user
    StrictHostKeyChecking no
    UserKnownHostsFile /dev/null
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/google_compute_engine
```